# What can I use hard, crunchy, leftover cookie-mistakes for?

Tags: baking

My husband made some chocolate chip cookies.  He changed the recipe (mistake) and they turned out flat and crispy.  They taste good, but do not look nice.  What can we use these for?  I hate to throw them all out - he made a double batch. Can I blend them up in the blender and make choc. chip pancakes or what.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: If they taste good, eat them. There is nothing wrong with a flat and crispy cookie, and it doesn't need to look like a work of art.  You can also crumble them up and use them for ice cream topping or similar.  Grinding them up to make something new is really a trick for *Chopped* where they *must* use strange ingredients; I would not do that at home.

Comment: I'd crumble them up and pour milk over them. Eat it with a spoon. Mmm. This is why I'm fat.

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/21531/67

Answer (score 10):

There are plenty of uses for less than ideal cookies.  Here are a few off the top of my head:

1. Crumble on top of yogurt, ice cream or other deserts
2. Crumble up and pack it down as a pie crust (although, chocolate chips might make this one messy)
3. Break up, and use in a bread pudding (but you have to let it soak for a while, and ***do not*** sweeten the custard, as you need to compensate for the sugar in the cookies)

Comment: 4) Hockey puck
5) Skeet-shooting target
6) Door stop
7) Paperweight

Answer (score 4):

What you need is some red icing, some white icing and some blue icing.  You can use this to make a little Union Jack on top of each cookie.

[image: Thinking of England]

Then, when you eat them, close your eyes and think of England.  It won't matter how they look.

Comment: Now that is fine humour :)