# Cookies are too sweet

Tags: baking

I made chocolate chip cookies and added too much brown sugar. The cookies are too sweet. I've used real butter and real chocolate chips. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you cooked them already?

Answer (score 5):

You might be able to overcome the sweetness by adding a tart glaze to the cookies (lemon or lime), but I don't know how well that'll go with the chocolate chips.  Another option would be to crush them up to make a yogurt parfait (made with plain, unsweetned yogurt).

You might also consider some of the options mentioned in [What can I use hard, crunchy, leftover cookie-mistakes for?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/40669/67)

Comment: +1 for parfait. Sprinkle those bad boys on some Greek yoghurt!

Comment: @PrestonFitzgerald : be careful of greek yogurts ... some are sweetened, even when 'plain'.    They're also naturally more sweet than normal yogurts (as they drain away the whey, concentrating the amount of sugars naturally occuring in the milk).

Answer (score 1):

I'd try "deepening" the chocolate flavour, thus reducing the percieved total sweetness: 
Make a simple ganache with 2 parts very dark chocolate and 1 part cream and use it to sandwich two cookies together. 
If you really want to go from mistake to fabulous, you could add some additional flavoring to the ganache, either something alcohol-based (Cointreau, rum, whiskey) or add spices (chili is somewhat en vouge with dark choc, cinnammon or "gingerbread" for a seasonal twist, tonka bean, ...)

Answer (score 1):

Try "frosting" the cookies with plain (unsweetened) peanut butter -- it will offset the sweetness and be delicious!

Answer (score -3):

There is nothing that you can do with your current batch of cookies (or eat with milk).

You just have to follow the recipe correctly and not add sugar as expected!!!

If after properly following the recipe, switch to another low(er) sugar recipe.

Use any internet search for "low sugar cookies" (or something similar).

Comment: And how does this answer the question or otherwise help them?

Comment: OP says he added too much sugar and the cookies are too sweet; there is not much to tell that OP needs to follow recipe or use recipe with less sugar.

Comment: I agree with @Joe. The OP already knows they made a mistake. That wasn't the question. This is a non-answer.

Comment: ok, so what was the question then ?

Comment: re "not an answer" - I think this is an answer, just a blatantly unhelpful one. If there really were nothing at all you could do with them, then that would be a fine answer, but as Joe has demonstrated, there *are* possibly things you can do with them.