# Fix for over spiced molasses cookies?

Tags: baking, cookies

I usually add more spices to my molasses cookies but this time, I added just a smidge too much. They are "good" but not "great" as I would like them to be for Thanksgiving. I made one batch and have the remaining batter in the fridge.
Can the batter be saved?? If not, do you have recommendations for a frosting to balance it out?

Cheers!

JJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have batter in the fridge you can make more batter without spices and mix the two before baking.

Something like a cream cheese (or other fairly substantial/thick) frosting might help the ones that are baked.

Answer (score 1):

I have a gingerbread cookie recipe that calls for dipping the cookies in white chocolate.  I suspect that would solve your issue if they’re only slightly over-spiced.

You might also consider using them as an ingredient or topping for something else: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/40670/67